# How to write Python classes that wrap Django ORM without circular references (for memcaching)?

Tags: python, django, caching, orm

My Django application contains the following two models:

```
# Start file person.py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254,null=False, blank=False,)

    @property
    def things(self):
        return self.Thing_created_by.all()
# End file person.py
```

and

```
# Start file thing.py
from person import Person
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254,null=False, blank=False,)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="Thing_created_by")
# End file thing.py
```

I want to write wrapper classes respectively named `CachedPerson` and `CachedThing`) that would be drop-in-replacements for these two classes. `CachedPerson` and `CachedThing` would act as a middleware to load instances of Person or Thing into memcached. If the instances were already loaded in memcached, they would be returned without hitting the Database of course.

The idea is that invoking `CachedPerson.__init__(self, pk=3)` would retrieve `Person.object.get(pk=3)` from the database, serialize it and then store it (and its children CachedThings) in memcached with a corresponding unique key. `CachedThing.__init__(self, pk=3)` would work analogously. Basically I'm replicating copies of my ORM and storing them in memcached to increase performance. All reads/writes to the ORM will be handled by these wrapper classes.

To illustrate this concept, here is what I want to be in memcached if Person #3 created Thing #4 and Thing #5:

```
{
    "Person_3": {
        "name": "Person #3",
        "things": [<CachedThing #4 Object>, <CachedThing #5 Object>],
    },
    "Thing_4": {
        "name": "Thing #4",
        "created_by": <CachedPerson #3 Object>,
    },
    "Thing_5": {
        "name": "Thing #5",
        "created_by": <CachedPerson #3 Object>,
    },
}
```

However, I'm struggling to write the `CachedPerson.__init__()` without getting caught with circular import references between CachedPerson and CachedThing. Calling `Person.object.get(pk=3).things()` returns Thing #4 and Thing #5. But to convert them to CachedThings, I need to call `CachedThing.__init__(pk=4)` and `CachedThing.__init__(pk=5)`. That requires importing CachedThing, which would cause circular imports. So how can it be done?

I wish Django had a middleware that would manage this complex ORM caching task for me. Alas it doesn't as far as I can tell. From what I have seen [**DjangoMemcached**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/) caches rendered HTML pages for me. That's not what I need. My entire Django app is a series of RESTful APIs. I'm not rendering any HTML. I need by Django Database Models held in the cache. Some of them are very complex and database intensive to access and modify.

Comment: No, the cache stores anything, not just HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can import inside functions/methods:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def things(self):
        from myapp.cachedthings import CachedThing
        ...
```

But I think that custom ModelManager is a better option for such task.  Google for "django cache model manager" - there is a lot of tips and apps created for this purpose.

Comment: The suggestion to look for a custom ModelManager was a very good suggestion. Thanks! I have been looking for months for some middleware to provide this functionality... but I couldn't find any via google. Searching for "Django cache model manager" did the trick! I found CacheMachine. It seems like a good solution.